# overriding virtual methods of another class while using interfaces instead of inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, coding-style, solid-principles

I want to use a modular design and I'm aiming to use compositions instead of inheritance so, how to override methods of compositions that I use in my main class?
it may seem vague so I'll explain it with a simplified example;

I have a main class called CharacterController:

```
public class CharacterController
{
    // some stuffs
}
```

I have my methods wrapped in classes:

```
public class MovementWays
{
    public virtual Vector2 MoveByKeyboard()
    {
        // reads keyboard input and return movement data
        return Result
    }
    public virtual Vector2 MoveByGeolocation()
    {
        // reads target point input and return movement data
        return Result
    }
    public virtual Vector2 MoveByTouch()
    {
        // reads touch input and return movement data
        return Result
    }
}

public class JumpingWays
{
    public virtual float JumpByKeyboard()
    {
        // reads keyboard input, do some calculations and return jumping data
        return Result
    }
    public virtual float JumpByTouch()
    {
        // reads touch input, do some calculations and return jumping data
        return Result
    }
}
```

I have interfaces:

```
public interface IMovementWays
{
    MovementWays handleMovements();
}
public interface IJumpingWays
{
    JumpingWays handleJumpings();
}
```

and finally, I want to use classes declared in the interfaces in my main class and override their methods like so;

```
public class CharacterController : IMovementWays, IJumpingWays
{
    // some stuffs
    
    public MovementWays handleMovements()
    {
        // override the three methods here like ->
        // 
        override handleMovements.MoveByKeyboard(){}...
        override handleMovements.MoveByGeolocation(){}...
        override handleMovements.MoveByTouch(){}...
    }
    
    public JumpingWays handleJumpings()
    {
        // override the two methods here like ->
        // 
        override handleJumpings.JumpByKeyboard(){}...
        override handleJumpings.JumpByTouch(){}...
    }
}
```

the point of separating methods to an interface is to have an undefined number of methods and use them in different controllers yet let them be customizable for each one.

I'm doing some exercises with SOLID and some other principles so my design might be completely wrong, I have searched about this problem for 2 days and haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: `class Fruit : IRipeFruit` implies that all fruit is ripe.

Comment: @mjwills no, there would be no inheritance, indeed the original example is a character controller and there would be two ways of controlling, one by key and one by target point in space. so it would be one controller class (fruit) with two methods (ripefruit) (they are just placeholders to simplify the problem) but I want to be able to change the methods if needed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman currently yes but there gonna be different interfaces added like ```UnripeFruit```

Comment: @mjwills So design-wise it's completely wrong? if I use an interface it means that I have to stick with its method completely and should not be able to alter its functionality?

Comment: @Mehrdad995 - it may look like nitpickung but when your example is inconsistent or illogical it's difficult to answer.

Comment: @mjwills As It's not apparently possible to have any logic in an interface but its declaration, I'm supposed to place that logic somewhere, that's why I wrapped that method in a class.

Comment: @mjwills thanks for the tip, changed the class type, it may now be less confusing.

Comment: @mjwills Also changed the namings, now it makes more sense.
the original concept is like so,
I have a player controller, and there are two ways of controlling it,
one by keyboard another by target points in space.
the controller here is (fruit) and one of those ways to control, let's say keyboard, is (pick fruit),
so in general, I want to use a bunch of methods and calculations in different classes in a modular way, so move by keyboard can be used in character controller as well as in object controller, and I want to be able to alter their functionalities at the same time for each.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have changed the question, now it's more clear.

Comment: @Mehrdad995 What you outline in your question isn't how composition works. MoveByKeyboard, MoveByGeolocation, MoveByTouch would all be different classes that implement an interface e.g. IMover with the common method names. Then you pass the actual implementation to the Constructor of your CharacterController and only call Methods that are defined on the interface. Something like e.g. MoveLeft()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding about composition vs inheritance. You will still need some kind of polymorphism in order to customize the behavior, but this but there should be few level of inheritance, and prefer to interface inheritance instead of implementation inheritance. In your example you could inherit from `MovementWays` and override all the functions, but if you do that, what is the point of `IMovementWays`?

say you have a character that can be controlled by both touch and keyboard, and can both be walking and driving. You could do something like this:

```
public class Character{
    public IMovement Movement {get};
}
public interface IMovement{
    void HandleTouch(...);
    void HandleKeyboard (...);
}
public class WalkingMovement : IMovement{
    private Character character;
    public WalkingMovement(Character c) => character = c;
    void HandleTouch(...){}
    void HandleKeyboard (...){}
}
public class DrivingMovement : IMovement{
    private Character character;
    public DrivingMovement (Character c) => character = c;
    void HandleTouch(...){}
    void HandleKeyboard (...){}
}
```

This lets the character replace the Movement object when entering/exiting a car, and allows splitting responsibility among several classes.

It might also be useful to lookup the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), since this allow both movement and input to be encapsulated in objects, while still allowing a unique method for each combination of objects.

Comment: That was actually a very smart solution, thank you (and sorry, my reputation score doesn't let me upvote).
so I can initialize the character with the customized movements I want and use the methods accordingly, right?:
[code image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17SVqnxB2z3REPUTOWOoGn2uKBQ-CUhni/view?usp=sharing)
however, this doesn't quite work, as I cant pass the uncreated class to the constructor.
isn't it better to change the `public IMovement Movement { get; }` to `public IMovement Movement { get; set; }` so that I can set the Movement on the go?

Comment: @Mehrdad995 Yes, if you want to control the movement from outside the character you need some kind of setter.